# How to sort a custom NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

I have a class officeSupply

```
@interface OfficeSupply : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *itemName;
@property (nonatomic) int total;
@property (nonatomic) int price;
@property (nonatomic) int quantity;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *quantityText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *itemPic;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)itemName total:(int)total price:(int)price quantity:(int)quantity picture:(UIImage *)itemPic;

@end
```

And in my view I have

```
 OfficeSupply *item1 = [[OfficeSupply alloc] initWithName:@"Stapler" total:0 price:50 quantity:0 picture:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stapler.jpg"]];
OfficeSupply *item2 = [[OfficeSupply alloc] initWithName:@"Paper" total:0 price:150 quantity:0 picture:[UIImage imageNamed:@"101291.jpg"]];
OfficeSupply *item3 = [[OfficeSupply alloc] initWithName:@"Pen" total:0 price:45 quantity:0 picture:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pen.jpg"]];
_items =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, item2, item3, nil];

[_items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"itemName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];
```

I've looked up the problem already but haven't been able to solve my problem.

The last line is supposed to sort it but I don't know why it won't.

I just want to sort them by name.. Any ideas?

Comment: It sorts the array just fine.  But you never assign that sorted array to anything -- it just falls on the floor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't edit an `NSArray` because it's immutable so you need to do:

```
_items = [_items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"itemName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];
```

Answer (score 3):

The call to `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` returns an NSArray instance, which is the sorted representation of the instance you call the method on. So:

```
NSArray *sortedItems = [_items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"itemName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];
```

You could also simply further by using literal syntax for your array of sort descriptors.

```
NSArray *sortedItems = [_items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"itemName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];
```

If you want to keep mutating the _items NSArray instance then create is as an NSMutableArray to start with.

```
// Make sure _items instance variable is declared as an NSMutableArray    
_items =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:item1, item2, item3, nil];

[_items sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"itemName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

TAke _items as NSMutableArray...

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray=[_items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"itemName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];

[_items removeAllObjects];
[_items addObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];
```